# Getting the name of the pod where the code is running

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am trying to get the name of the pod from which response is coming, instead of getting the name of the pod, I am getting the name of the worker node in which the pod is present. I have also included the following code snippet in the YAML but I am still getting the worker node name. Please tell me if I am missing something?

```
 - env:
     - name: HOSTNAME
       valueFrom:
         fieldRef:
           apiVersion: v1
             fieldPath: metadata.name
```

I am expecting to get the podname instead of worker node address in the HOSTNAME value.

Comment: How are you requesting for the pod ? Can you provide that information, otherwise it is difficult to help.

Comment: I am requesting a pod through deployment ->  replicaset -> pod

Comment: I meant, through the CLI/Openshift web console/code ?

Comment: I am doing through Openshift CLI (through oc commands)

Comment: please past the entire yaml

Comment: I am not able to paste the entire yaml as it is too long

Comment: I got the solution ,  in the yaml for  dnsPolicy : ClusterFirstWithHostNet I replaced it with  dnsPolicy : ClusterFirst . Thank you all ! it was my first question on stackoverflow and your help was amazing

Answer (score 0):

If you run:

oc exec <name_of_the_pod> -- echo $HOSTNAME

you would get the name of the pod, but since you will need the name to execute the command, I am not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Knowing the name of the pod from within a container running on it, can be achieved reading the value of the $HOSTNAME variable.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the `$HOSTNAME` variable somehow inherited from a node. Try using the official Kubernetes `$POD_NAME` for this purpose:

```yaml
env:
 - name: POD_NAME
   valueFrom:
     fieldRef:
       fieldPath: metadata.name
```

By the way, you can add both of them and play around:

```bash
kubectl exec <name_of_the_pod> -- echo $HOSTNAME
kubectl exec <name_of_the_pod> -- echo $POD_NAME
```

Comment: I got the solution , in the yaml for dnsPolicy : ClusterFirstWithHostNet I replaced it with dnsPolicy : ClusterFirst